# Apphabor gives 404 on bootstrap.less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-404, less, appharbor

I have deployed a simple .NET MVC application on appharbor that implements bootstrap and less. The less loads fine on my localhost instance when i run it, however, when i push it to appharbor i get a 404 on bootstrap.less.

Has anyone run into this before that might be able to tell me why?

I have checked the buildout and the less directory/file structure exists on the deployment.

The appharbor url is http://appharbor-bootstrap.apphb.com/ if anyone wants to check out what im seeing.

Source can be found on github 
https://github.com/jamesamuir/appharbor-bootstrap

This is what it is supposed to look like [image: localhost]

This is what it looks like on appharbor [image: appharbor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to configure the mime-type mapping in your web.config. There are links to details [here](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/717-less-file-is-not-being-served) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025145/dotless-file-yields-404-error-in-iis).

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I updated the web.config and deployed it and am still receiving the same result.

Comment: It turns out that the build action for the .less files was set to "none" even though I had thought i had set it to "content". Updating that and redeploying solved my issue. Thanks again for the reply!